# Revenue problem with 3 dollar decreases

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A soccer stadium has on average 4000 fans when the ticket price is 13 dollars. For every 3 dollar decrease, the attendance rises by 1750 fans.

Write a function where x is the ticket price.

Would the answer be x(4000+1750((20-x)/3)?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Write a function for what?  From the title, it seems to be total revenue, but you should say that.  Where do you get the $20-x$ term?  The baseline ticket price is $13$.

Answer (score 0):

If the function you need to write is the revenue function, recall the revenue function $R(x)$ multiplies the cost of the tickets and the number of tickets sold. We know:

> $R(0)=13(4000)$
>      $R(1)=10(4000 + 1750)$
>      $R(2)=7(4000 + 1750\cdot2)$

...and so on. But here, $x$ is not the ticket price but the number of 3-dollar decreases in ticket price. If $x$ is the ticket price, we have a linear function that is not very interesting. But the revenue function is of more interest because it informs the soccer team how much to charge for a ticket *in order to get the most income (revenue)*.

Can you write the function from the hints I have provided?